# Computing discrete logarithms in the subgroup generated by 1 + N

Tags: discrete-logarithm, group-theory

When I read about DLP, I found that there are groups where the computation is easy. I found that it is known that computing discrete logarithms in the subgroup generated by 1 + N is easy. For example : $ (1+N)^{x} = 1+ xN  $. Is this correct? And what is the mathematical foundation of this computation?  Why is considered as easy compared to the other groups?

Comment: subgroup of which group?

Comment: If we are in $\Bbb Z_N$, it holds $(1+N)^x=1=1+x\,N$ making the generated group  rather boring. Thus it's essential to state what base ring (or other algebraic structure) is used.

Comment: This is true in the [Paillier group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paillier_cryptosystem) and the property is exploited in the decryption procedure.

Comment: Occams_Trimmer, could you please provide me more details?

Comment: The Wikipedia entry ([Background](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paillier_cryptosystem#Background) section) is quite detailed.